# Gunicorn and Supervisor error file does not have executable permissions

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm trying to run this command:

```
sudo supervisorctl start gunicorn_process
```

On Ubuntu and I get this error:

[image]

As you can see the file 'does' have executable permissions.

**gunicorn_process file:**

```
[program:gunicorn_process]
command=/srv/domain wsgi:application
directory=/srv/domain
user=root
```

Comment: Your command looks funky. Is `/srv/domain` a directory or an executable command?

Comment: @msvalkon its a directory

Comment: @Spike and then what is the application? Can you run `wsgi:application` from `/srv/domain`?

Comment: @msvalkon running this I can "gunicorn wsgi:application"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `command` directive requires an executable command which supervisor runs.

You say you want to run

```
gunicorn wsgi:application
```

then set your configuration like so:

```
[program:gunicorn_process]
command=gunicorn wsgi:application
directory=/srv/domain
user=root
```

Two things to take into account:

1. You should not run your wsgi app as root. There's a potential security issue right there. Create a user which has no extra privileges which is only meant to run your web applications and servers.
2. You might want to change the `command` directive to include the full path of `gunicorn` executable. Do a `which gunicorn` to find out where it exists. For example: `command=/usr/bin/gunicorn wsgi:application`

Answer (score 3):

Make the file executable: `sudo chmod u+x gunicorn_process`